# Repeating find_package for additional components only

Tags: cmake, package, cmakelists-options

I am new to Cmake. I have a `CMakeLists.txt` like below for an app which runs on Windows and Linux.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)

find_package(Qt5 COMPONENTS Qml Quick)

if(UNIX AND NOT APPLE)
    find_package(Qt5 COMPONENTS Core Network)
endif()
```

**Question:**
I have a `find_package` call to get `Qml` and `Quick` which are two `Qt5` components. This is good and required for both Windows and Linux cases. But in the case specific to Linux only, I want `find_package` to only look for `Core` and `Network` without mentioning `Qt5`. Is it possible?

I tried `find_package(Core Network)` and `find_package(Qt5::Core Qt5::Network)`. Both didn't work.

Below if else is the only way?

```
if(WIN32)
    find_package(Qt5 COMPONENTS Qml Quick)
else()
    find_package(Qt5 COMPONENTS Qml Quick Core Network)
endif()
```

I don't want to do the above if else and thats my point here. I want to do something like this which looks incremental

```
find_package(Qt5 COMPONENTS Qml Quick)
if(UNIX AND NOT APPLE)
    find_package(Core Network) # But this does not compile
else()
```

Comment: "I want `find_package` to only do a `find_package` to link to `Core` and `Network` without re-linking to `Qt5`" - Not sure what do you mean by "re-linking": `find_package` does link nothing, it just **searches** for a libraries. Repeating `find_package` is perfectly supported.

Comment: I meant is it not possible to do a `find_package(Qml Quick)` without mentioning `Qt5` ?

Comment: I have tried to explain my question better and more accurately now.

Comment: No, `find_package(Qml Quick)` is not correct. How `find_package` would know, that `Qml` and `Quick` are components for QT, and not for something else? Note, that `find_package` command is intended for search any packages, not just QT5. Your first code snippet is perfectly good.

Comment: If you don't like repeating some parameters or functions calls, then you are free to define your own function/macro/variable for avoid repeating. E.g. you may create a variable which contains required components: `set(REQUIRED_QT_COMPONENTS Qml Quick)` and conditionally add some components to it: `list(APPEND REQUIRED_QT_COMPONENTS Core Network)`. After all components are specified, call `find_package(Qt5 COMPONENTS ${REQUIRED_QT_COMPONENTS}`.